# How to add two image in canvas element in html..?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So far, I create a canvas and I add two images one over another.how to create a eraser to scratch upper image and then shows it lower image ..pls help me..

It's very essential to me ..I surprise to my brother birthday...pls help me..Thank you..
I just want to know..

1. how to add two images on canvas? In my code is it right..?
2. how to create eraser for clearing upper image.. with touchmove in javaScript

**javaScript**

```
window.addEventListener("click",play);
function play() { document.getElementById("song").play();
}
window.onload = function () {
       
       var img1= new Image();
       
        img1.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xxz0nbrplhst2w2/20201010_174008.jpg?';
        img1.onload = function () 
        {
            filling1(img1);       
        }
        
        
        var img2=new Image();
  
        img2.src= 
"https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zpoxft30lzrr5mg/20201012_102150.jpg";
  img2.onload = function () 
        {
            filling2(img2);       
        }
        
        
        function filling1(img) {
 var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;      
       ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,1012,1012);
            
        }
        
        
        function filling2(img) {
 var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;      
       ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,1078,1260);
            
        }
        
     }
```

**CSS**

```
body { background: #dddddd;
 }
 canvas 
 { 
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: thin inset #aaaaaa; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 400px; 
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url("");
 
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head> 
 <title>Canvas</title>
 
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
 
 </head>
 <body> 
 <div>
 <canvas id="canvas"> Canvas not supported </canvas> 
 </div>
 <audio controls style="display:none;"loop id="song" >
 <source src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bsgain4rsi5q44m/Happy-Birthday-Instrumental">
    <!--   <source src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bbxas9a8jvts3ng/birthday%20wishes%20song%20slow%20motion">   -->
  
  <script>
   
   
  Swal.fire("Just Scratch It").then((value)=> {Swal.fire('I hope you like it','Thank you','success');});

  </script>
  
  </audio>
 
 
 </body> 
</html>
```

**It is another code for touchmove but it doesn't work as a eraser ..why..?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 380;
var mx, my;
function Circle(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = 30;
    this.draw = function(){
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.stroke();
}
    this.update = function(){
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove",      
    function(e){
    mx = e.touches[0].clientX;
    my = e.touches[0].clientY;
    circle.x = mx;
    circle.y = my;
});
    if(this.x + this.radius > canvas.width){
    this.x = canvas.width / 2;
}
    if(this.x - this.radius < 0){
     this.x = canvas.width / 2;   
    }
    if(this.y + this.radius > canvas.height){
    this.y = canvas.height / 2;
}
    if(this.y - this.radius < 0){
     this.y = canvas.height / 2;   
    }
     circle.draw()
}
}

var circle = new Circle(100, 100);
function a(){
    requestAnimationFrame(a);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle.update();
}
a();
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("click",play);
function play() { document.getElementById("song").play();}

var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 400;

window.onload = function () {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,300,400);
  img.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zpoxft30lzrr5mg/20201012_102150.jpg";
}

function Circle(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = 30;
  this.draw = function(){  
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
var circle = new Circle(100, 100);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
    var mx = e.touches[0].clientX;
    var my = e.touches[0].clientY;
    move(mx, my);
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    var mx = e.offsetX;
    var my = e.offsetY;
    move(mx, my);
});

function move(x,y){
  circle.x = x;
  circle.y = y;
  circle.draw();
}
```

```css
body { background: #dddddd;}
canvas { 
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: thin inset #aaaaaa; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 400px;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xxz0nbrplhst2w2/20201010_174008.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head> 
   <title>Canvas</title>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
   <div>
     <canvas id="canvas"> Canvas not supported </canvas> 
   </div>
  <audio controls style="display:none;"loop id="song" >
  <source src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bsgain4rsi5q44m/Happy-Birthday-Instrumental">
    <!--   <source src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bbxas9a8jvts3ng/birthday%20wishes%20song%20slow%20motion">   -->
  </audio>
  <script> 
    Swal.fire("Just Scratch It").then((value)=> {Swal.fire('I hope you like it','Thank you','success');});
  </script>  
 </body> 
</html>
```